# MySQL join with count and where

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to fetch all discussions and add the count of all UserDiscussion rows where column 'bookmarked' is true for the discussion.

```
Table: Discussion
-----------------
DiscussionID
Name
.....


Table: UserDiscussion
---------------------
UserID
DiscussionID
Bookmarked (Boolean)
```

This is my query but it is not correct:

```
SELECT d.*, COUNT(*) as BookmarkCount
FROM Discussion d
LEFT JOIN UserDiscussion ud
ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID
WHERE ud.Bookmarked = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to write this is:

```
SELECT d.*, COUNT(ud.DiscussionID) as BookmarkCount
FROM Discussion d LEFT JOIN
     UserDiscussion ud
     ON ud.DiscussionID = d.DiscussionID AND
        ud.Bookmarked = true
GROUP BY d.DiscussionId;
```

The changes are:

- Using `COUNT()` on a field from the *second* table.  This will count the number of matches. `COUNT(*)` will never return `0`, in this case (the group would be filtered out).
- Moving the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `WHERE` condition would filter out `NULL` values, turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join.
- Adding a `GROUP BY` clause so you get one row per discussion id.

Note:  Grouping by `DiscussionId` is fine, assuming that it is the primary key on `Discussion`.  In general, it is better to include all unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY`.  But it is okay (and compliant with ANSI SQL), when the `GROUP BY` is by a primary/unique key.

Comment: ...and your server's rules allow it.